# SPARQL Query - get top-level classes of a dataset

Tags: class, sparql

How can I get only the top-level classes of a dataset?
The query below returns also the sub-classes (of the top level classes)
which I do not need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class 
WHERE {
?s a ?class .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out any classes that have a subClassOf predicate, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class 
WHERE {
  ?s a ?class .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?parent . } 
}
```

Comment: in case of OWL datasets it might be necessary to add also a filter on `owl:Thing` class, i.e. `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?parent . FILTER(?parent != owl:Thing)}`